# Veritas alternatives for MQ file sharing

Tags: ibm-mq, failovercluster

We have an application that can use only one MQ queue manager to put/get messages, so to get High availability we are using an active/passive cluster with IP & File system sharing between 2 linux servers and veritas service taking care of failing over the resources. While this is a working soulution we are running into multiple issues and being limited to using physical servers over a VM.
I'm looking for a solution that can replace Veritas, something that can be run on VM and takes care of moving filesystem/IP between servers seamlessly.
There is a service in MQ Advanced that can do this but is considerably expensive than base, so not really interested.
Anyone with similar MQ architecture or know a product that can do such failover please share any details.

Thanks!

Comment: standard MQ supports also Multi Instance (MI), this requires a shared file system but it can be NFSv4, I have heard of people using this in a VM world.  IBM just had a presentation at it's techcon last week from LL Bean and they use the MQ Advanced RDQM on VMs with great success.

Comment: @JoshMc - Thanks for this suggestion, I'm reading up on this and will soon do a POC to check if it works will all our use cases.
I had invite to the techcon but just got so busy that had to miss it!

Comment: They said all the recorded sessions will be available for one year.   Just sign up after and you should have access.